# Super, Constructor,Intent Service and SQLite Database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, constructor

I know how to do SQLite Database, when doing it specifically in its own dedicated java class. But whenever i want it to be inside of something, in this case, an Intent Service, it always give me errors, and i can't debug it.

```
package my.skul;


    import android.app.IntentService;
    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

    public class CheckClassroom extends IntentService {

                /**
                 * A constructor is required, and must call the super IntentService(String)
                 * constructor with a name for the worker thread.
                 */
                public CheckClassroom() {
                    super("CheckClassroom");
                }

                /**
                 * The IntentService calls this method from the default worker thread with
                 * the intent that started the service. When this method returns,
                 * IntentService stops the service, as appropriate.
                 */
                @Override
                protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {





                }
                private DbHelper ourHelper;
                private final Context ourContext;
                private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

                private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

                    public DbHelper(Context context) {
                        super(context, "myschool", null, 1);
                        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    public CheckClassroom(Context c) {
                        ourContext = c;
                    }

                    public CheckClassroom open() {
                        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
                        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                        return this;

                    }

                    public void close() {
                        ourHelper.close();
                    }

            }
                getColumns()
                {
                    //retrieve sqlitedatabase data

                }


    }
```

I've been reading a lot about constructor, but i can't really fully understand it, explaining all my errors here would really give me a better understanding of this. Thanks..

Comment: when i hover in  public CheckClassroom() {
                    super("CheckClassroom");
                }The blank final field ourContext may not have been initialized

Comment: public CheckClassroom(Context c) {
                        ourContext = c;
                    } is inside DbHelper.

Comment: thanks, though the "CheckClassroom() { super("CheckClassroom"); }The blank final field ourContext may not have been initialized" is still there, and when i hover in  public CheckClassroom(Context c) {
                        ourContext = c;
                    } it says, Implicit super constructor IntentService() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when i hover in public CheckClassroom() { super("CheckClassroom");
>   }The blank final field ourContext may not have been initialized

Because you declared the `DbHelper` class static, it will create an instance as soon as the `CheckClassroom` is instantiated. At that time, ourContext is still not initialized.

To fix this, remove the static for the `DbHelper` class and make one instance to be a static field instead. Then in the constructor you can initialize that (after you initialize ourContext).

```
private static DbHelper myDbHelper;

public CheckClassroom() {
    super("CheckClassroom");
    ourContext = this;
    myDbHelper = new DbHelper();
}
```

And instead of using ourContext, you can just use `CheckClassroom.this` in the `DbHelper` class.

Also...

The `public CheckClassroom(Context c) { ourContext = c; }` function has nothing to do inside the `DbHelper` class....

Also that open and close functions do not seem right, instead I think you should override onCreate and onDestroy

Here is your code, fixed:

```
package my.skul;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class CheckClassroom extends IntentService {

            /**
             * A constructor is required, and must call the super IntentService(String)
             * constructor with a name for the worker thread.
             */
            public CheckClassroom() {
                super("CheckClassroom");
            }

            /**
             * The IntentService calls this method from the default worker thread with
             * the intent that started the service. When this method returns,
             * IntentService stops the service, as appropriate.
             */
            @Override
            protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {





            }
            private DbHelper ourHelper;
            private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

            @Override
            public void onCreate() {
                ourHelper = new DbHelper();
                ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroy() {
                ourHelper.close();
            }

            private class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

                public DbHelper() {
                    super(CheckClassroom.this, "myschool", null, 1);
                    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                }

                @Override
                public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            }
            /* not sure what that is... 
            getColumns()
            {
                //retrieve sqlitedatabase data

            }
            */
}
```

Comment: thanks, but honestly i still dont get it,  can u post my code with your editing, ill take it from there, i really dont know what to debug.

Comment: it has error when i try to call this, i tried to create a table inside the oncreate sqlite  arg0.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ASX (MY_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT(50));");... it gives me error.."Could not execute method of the activity" in the logcat

Comment: that's a different problem..... the code I put there does not have any error anymore. If you add more code to add more errors, you should accept this one and create a new question